# Fall back to hotspot when no Wi-Fi network is available

Tags: wireless, hot-spot, headless

I am running Kubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I want my Wi-Fi card to create a hotspot if it cannot find one of the networks to connect to. I plan on taking this system out in the boonies and want to run headless using VNC so I need this to switch automatically when it detects the boonies.

Comment: I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect. You could probably adapt it for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't had a chance to explore it yet.